# How to force re-use of connections in jdbc pool?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've got a Runnable which gets a connection from a connection pool as below and has 60 seconds to do something with the connection:

```
private static ConnectionPoolDataSource cpds; // MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource

public void run(){
    while((System.currentTimeMillis()-created)<60000){
        try(Connection conn = cpds.getPooledConnection().getConnection()){  
            //do something
        }catch(SQLException sqle){}
    }
}
```

When the thread dies after 60s, i've assumed the connection is returned to the pool and when a new thread is created the connection can be re-used. But when I list my network connections, the list keeps growing as more threads are created. Are connections created as above being returned to the pool correctly and if so how can I force the connections to be re-used ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not actually using a connection pool. A `ConnectionPoolDataSource` isn't intended to be used directly. It is intended as a (special) `DataSource` for `PooledConnection` objects which are then kept in a connection pool by a (normal) `DataSource` implementation that provides connection pooling.

A normal developer should not use a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` directly, it is intended for use with connection pools provided by Application Servers, or to be wrapped into general purpose `DataSource`s that provide connection pooling.

When a `Connection` is requested from the connection pool, it will checkout an existing `PooledConnection` (or request a new one from its `ConnectionPoolDataSource`), retrieve a `Connection` and return that to the user. When the user closes the `Connection`, the `PooledConnection` will signal the connection pool that it is available again.

In this case you are creating a `PooledConnection`, retrieving a `Connection` from it and then discarding the `PooledConnection`. This means that the `PooledConnection` gets abandoned, and its physical connection to the database cannot be reused and will be closed/discarded when it is finally garbage collected (normally when the connection pool wants to close the physical connection, it will call `close()` on the `PooledConnection`).

You either need to use connection pooling as provided by your Application Server, or use a general purpose connection pool like DBCP, c3p0 or HikariCP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes this isn't using a connection pool at all. Saw [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353569/am-i-using-java-pooledconnections-correctly) as well which cleared things up a little.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you're using for a connection pool, so the answer is "maybe."

However, most pools have some way to detect abandoned connections. For example, [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html) gives you the `removeAbandoned` and `removeAbandonedTimeout` configuration parameters. These won't immediately return the connection to the pool, so you'll still see the number of connections growing until the timeout expires (and hopefully, since you're in a tight loop, you've set a maximum on the number of open connections).

Comment: Thanks. Using MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource - i'll check the api.