# Oracle Connection Pool Class

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, connection-pooling

I want to setup a connection pool for a Oracle DB in a Helper class.

```
public class DbConnection {

// Data source for the pooled connection
private static OracleDataSource dataSource;

// Host
private static final String dbHost = "bla";

// Port
private static final String dbPort = "1521";

// DBname
private static final String database = "orcl";

// DBuser
private static final String dbUser = "bla";

// DBpassword
private static final String dbPassword = "bla";

static {
    OracleConnectionPoolDataSource opds;
    try {
        opds = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();
        opds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort + ":"
                + database);
        opds.setUser(dbUser);
        opds.setPassword(dbPassword);
        dataSource = opds;
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.err.println("Connection failed!");
    }
    try {
        // Load driver
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Driver not found!");
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}
}
```

This is working but it is not awfully fast so I think I'm missing something to get the pooling working. Any suggestions?

So my externel classes just invoke the getConnection() method ...

```
Connection conn = DbConnection.getConnection();
...
conn.close();
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "not awfully fast"? Which part exactly is slow? Opening a connection to Oracle *can* take some time. Did you check out the manual regarding connection caching? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/concache.htm#CDEGABII

Comment: Read the link I posted. It says the "*OracleConnectionCache*" is deprecated, not the section I linked to. Btw: why don't you use a connection pool like DBCP or C3P0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` directly. It is intended for use by a connection pool in an application server. It does not provide connection pooling itself. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/12651163/466862

In other words: You need to use an actual connection pool, like DBCP, c3p0 or BoneCP, or the UCP (Universal Connection Pool).

Answer (score 2):

`oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.setConnectionCachingEnabled` documentation state the following:

> Deprecated. Use Oracle Universal Connection Pool instead.

You can download [Oracle Database UCP](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/ucp-112010-099129.html) and create your `DataSource` as follows:

```
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory;

PoolDataSource poolDataSource = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
poolDataSource.setConnectionFactoryClassName(OracleDataSource.class.getName());
poolDataSource.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE");
poolDataSource.setUser("SYSTEM");
poolDataSource.setPassword("****");
```

Comment: Why would they deprecate something and then make you download what you're supposed to use...

Comment: "We expect you to stop using this function and use this other function instead, which we have not provided with the language, for your inconvenience."

Answer (score 1):

You need you to use OracleDataSource (not OracleConnectionPoolDataSource) and set setConnectionCachingEnabled(true).

```
     private  static OracleDataSource ods = null;
     ...
     static {
        System.out.println("OracleDataSource Initialization");
        try {
            ods = new OracleDataSource();
            ods.setConnectionCachingEnabled(true);
            ods.setConnectionCacheName("mycache");
            ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server.local:1521/prod");
            ods.setUser("scott");
            ods.setPassword("tiger");
            Properties cacheProps = new Properties();
            cacheProps.setProperty("MinLimit", "1");
            cacheProps.setProperty("MaxLimit", "4");
            cacheProps.setProperty("InitialLimit", "1");
            cacheProps.setProperty("ConnectionWaitTimeout", "5");
            cacheProps.setProperty("ValidateConnection", "true");
            ods.setConnectionCacheProperties(cacheProps);

        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
...
    public static Connection getConnection()
       throws SQLException {
      return ods.getConnection();
    }
```

Comment: Eclipse tells me setConnectionCachingEnabled is deprecated?

Comment: It's deprecated but it's still working fine with the current Oracle JDBC driver. If you are not comfortable with that fact then there are many alternatives like Proxool or C3PO.