# MySQL DataSource with connection pooling, setting URL at run-time

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling, mysql-connector

I have a Java service running in Tomcat that makes some tens of short database reads from a MySQL database per second. Obviously, I need a DataSource with connection pooling.
I obtain the connection string from a secure storage at run-time, so the most known way of obtaining a DataSource instance via JNDI from container does not seem to be applicable in my case.

I found 2 possible solutions and I'm hesitating between them.

1. Creating a MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource instance in my code - appeals to me more because it is not coupled with a specific container. However, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2353593/456181) claims that this is totally wrong.
2. Using Tomcat's DataSource and PoolProperties from org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool as in the ["Plain Ol' Java" example](https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html#Plain_Ol'_Java)

Answer (score 2):

Or a third way, that basically is to use Apache Commons Database Pooling AKA commons-pooling, that lets you create database pools programatically:

```
private BasicDataSource pool = new BasicDataSource();

pool.setDriverClassName(driver);
pool.setUrl(url);
pool.setUsername(user);
pool.setPassword(pass);
pool.setInitialSize(size);
```

After this, you can use `pool` to do what you want. Of course you can use other `DataSource` implementations.

This way you don't get coupled to tomcat, neither you need container configuration files.